# DatagridRow's mouseover not working properly

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I have the following styles for my datagrid :

```
<Style x:Key="StyleDataGrid" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single" />
        <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="FullRow" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="Horizontal" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Helvetica" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                            <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Background="Transparent" Name="text" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                Height="auto" Width="auto" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter  Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <!--<Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Content.Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>-->
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CouleurFond}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=CouleurTexte}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

But the mouseOver event on my DataGridRow doesn't work. When My mouse is over a row, the row 's Background is red but the text's foreground remains Black on all my columns excepted the cell under my mouse where the text became white as expected.

But I'd like to have all my line's foreground white when my mouse is over a row. What is wrong with my styles ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick was to add these lines to manage the mouse over event of my DataGridCell:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=CouleurBoutonHover}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=CouleurTexteBoutonHover}" />
        </DataTrigger>
```

and it was working :)

Answer (score 1):

If you comment out your other `Style`s temporarily, you'll see that actually, your `DataGridRow Style` works just fine... the `Background` of the selected `DataGridRow` is `Orange` as you required:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CouleurFond}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=CouleurTexte}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style
```

Therefore, you need to set your other `Style`s more carefully. Add them part by part and keep running the program occasionally to check that your problem hasn't reappeared and if it has, just undo the last edit or two, as that was what was causing your problem.

---

UPDATE >>>

Please read my last paragraph again:

> you need to set your other `Style`s more carefully. **Add them part by part** and keep running the program occasionally to **check that your problem hasn't reappeared** and if it has, just undo the last edit or two, as that was what was causing your problem.

*Add them part by part* does *not* mean add the whole `DataGridCell Style` back in one go as you clearly have done. If you *had* added the `setter`s back into the `DataGridCell Style` *part by part* then you would have noticed which `setter` is causing the problem for you.

Comment: Thank you. Also, Is there a way to bind the mouseover of the dataGridRow parent ?

Comment: What are you referring to as the parent of the `DataGridRow`?

Comment: I mean the DataGridRow which contains the DataGridCell which has the mouse over it

Comment: Then what are you talking about? Look again at your code example and read my answer again... that is exactly what this code does... as mentioned, *your `DataGridRow Style` works just fine... the `Background` of the selected `DataGridRow` is `Orange` as you required* (on mouse over).

Comment: Yes but I'd also like to set the foreground of my DataGridCells but when the mouse is over the row I want all my row's Foreground to become White. This is not working now because I set the foreground of cells. That's why I was asking maybe we can add a trigger on the parent mouse over to change the foreground when the mouse is over a cell of the same row.